# Where should "area" be placed in RouteData? In Values or in DataTokens?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to create a `RouteData` object in ASP.NET MVC and pass it around. Where should the "area" value be placed in `RouteData`? In `Values` or in `DataTokens`?

I'm confused because "area" *seems* to belong in `DataTokens` whereas "controller" and "action" *seem* to belong in `Values`. Is that correct? Why isn't the placement uniform?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, data tokens is used for view location, area is needed in there to correctly pick the locations to search for views.

If you want to use the UrlHelper classes etc to build a url, you will also need to add it to the RouteValues for them to accurately set the path to your controllers.